# How to disable javascript code from a javascript module?

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I have this Joomla module with a javascript listener, waiting for the mouse to hover an area. I want to disable the listener, I can do this in firebug by clicking the disable code option, but I want a more permanent javascripty approach. The code is minimized and It's hard to read, I can get this code from firebug, it is:

```
(function (a){a=new DOMEvent(a,j.getWindow());i.call(j,a)===false&&a.stop()})
```

Is there any javascript code that can disable that line of code? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have jquery try

```
jQuery('yourelement').off('hover mouseover');
```

or

```
jQuery('document').on('hover mouseover', '#yourlement', function(event){event.preventDefault();return false;})
```